# Importing data from geonames.org database into MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, geonames

Does anyone how to import a geonames.org data into my database? The one i'm trying to import is http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/DO.zip, and my DB its a MySQL db.

Comment: are you try to import zip ? if not what is file structure ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the following by looking in the readme file included in the zip file you linked to in the section called "The main 'GeoName' table has the following fields:"

First create the database and table on your MySQL instance. The type of fields are given in each row of the section I just quoted the title of above.

```
CREATE DATABASE DO_test;
CREATE TABLE `DO_test`.`DO_table` (
  `geonameid` INT,
  `name` varchar(200),
  `asciiname` varchar(200),
  `alternatenames` varchar(5000),
  `latitude` DECIMAL(10,7),
  `longitude` DECIMAL(10,7),
  `feature class` char(1),
  `feature code` varchar(10),
  `country code` char(2),
  `cc2` char(60),
  `admin1 code` varchar(20),
  `admin2 code` varchar(80),
  `admin3 code` varchar(20),
  `admin4 code` varchar(20),
  `population` bigint,
  `elevation` INT,
  `gtopo30` INT,
  `timezone` varchar(100),
  `modification date` date
)
CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

After the table is created you can import the data from the file.  The fields are delimited by tabs, rows as newlines:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file/DO.txt' INTO TABLE `DO_test`.`DO_table`;
```

Comment: Oops, you're gonna need to do something different with latitude & longitude.  I'm working on fixing that.  I think they should be "POINT" instead of DECIMAL.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting:
Error Code: 29
File '/home/blueprint/DO.txt' not found (Errcode: 13)

I'm pretty sure the file is there.

Comment: @LuisDUrraca: Are you on a mac?  Errorcode 13 means that MySQL is not able to see the file.  I have a mac and I put my DO.txt file in the Mac's mysql directory.  Easier than figuring out why MySQL couldn't see a file that was full read for everyone.  On my machine this is in /usr/local/mysql.

Comment: I'm on Linux Ubuntu 10.10. my MySQL dir is var/lib/mysql but cannot access that either. Let me keep trying.

Comment: @LuisDUrraca:  Do you mean you get error 13 there as well or that you can't put the file there?

Comment: I can't put the file on MySQL directory. Apparently other have had the same issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/244406

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=822084

Comment: @LuisDUrraca: Did you try putting it in /tmp and loading it from there?

Comment: i got it... Thank you very much. I followed the advice on those forums. I was able to import the data now in MySQL. But now that i look at the data i see that is not useful for my purposes but learned a couple of things while at it. What i really want is a list of all street, borough, etc., of my city because i want to create a database so i can get 5 nearest point of interest from a given point. If you could take a look at the following post and see if you can help: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277636/designing-a-normalize-database-for-getting-5-nearest-neighbor-using-mysql-spatial

Comment: @wilbbe01 How long does the import process take :D. I have 4 cores and the import is past 15 minutes now and going on..

Comment: @wofgang - cores probably don't have a whole lot to do with how fast this imports, but 15 minutes does seem long.

Comment: Here is the table structure if you just want the list of cities with postcodes: https://pastebin.com/2VTHv76g
By the way, currently Geonames data only needs latitude with DECIMAL(6,4) and longitude with DECIMAL(7,4).
I also read that it is better to avoid spaces in column names.
You can also import data with mysqlimport command.
There were errors because of backslashes so I had to remove them: `tr -d '\\' < geonames_cities.txt > cities.csv`

Comment: Edit: we don't need to remove backslashes if we add `sql-mode=""` below `[mysqld]` in my.cnf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606483/how-to-allow-empty-string-for-integer-in-mysql/28614512#comment70645059_28614512

Answer (score 17):

I have made recently a shell script that downloads the latest data from geonames site and imports them into a MySQL database. It is based on the knowledge at GeoNames Forum and saved me a lot of time.

It is in its first version but is fully functional. Maybe it can help.

You can access it at http://codigofuerte.github.com/GeoNames-MySQL-DataImport/

Comment: Thanks. This saved us some trouble. Seems to even work with Cygwin (saw it at my colleagues computer). Have it running at my linux box right now. Seems to work, but takes sooooo long! :)

Comment: Thanks, this proved very useful

Answer (score 8):

For every one in the future :
On geonames.org forum in the year 2008, this is "import all geonames dump into MySQL"
http://forum.geonames.org/gforum/posts/list/732.page

Also google this : import dump into [postgresql OR SQL server OR MySQL] site:forum.geonames.org

To find more answers even from the year 2006

**Edited to provide a synopsis:**

In the geoname official read me : http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/. We will find a good description about the dump files and contents of them.

Dump files will be imported to the MySQL datatable directly. for example :

```
SET character_set_database=utf8;
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/data/countryInfo.txt' INTO TABLE _geo_countries IGNORE 51 LINES(ISO2,ISO3,ISO_Numeric,FIPSCode,AsciiName,Capital,Area_SqKm,Population,ContinentCode,TLD,CurrencyCode,CurrencyName,PhoneCodes,PostalCodeFormats,PostalCodeRegex,Languages,GeonameID,Neighbours,EquivalentFIPSCodes);
SET character_set_database=default;
```

be careful about the characterset because if we use the CSV LOAD DATA ready importer of an old phpmyadmin of 2012 we may lose the utf characters even if the collation of columns was set to utf8_general_ci

Currently there are 4 essential datatables : continents, countries(countryInfo.txt), divisions(admin1), cities or locations(geonames)

admin1, 2, 3, 4 dump files are the different levels of internal divisions of countries such as admin 1 which is the states of US or provinces of other countries. admin 2 is more detailed and is the internal divisions of the state or the province. and so on for the 3 and 4

The countries dump files have been listed there contain not only cities but all the locatoins in that country even including a store center. Also there is a huge file as "allCountries.txt" will be more than 1GB after extracting from zip file. If we want only the cities we should choose one of the dump files : cities1000.txt , cities5000.txt , cities15000.txt which the numbers represent the min population of the listed cities. We store cities in the geonames datatable(you may call it geo locations or geo cities).

Before importing *.txt dump files take a few research about the LOAD DATA syntax in the MySQL documentation.

The read me text file(also in the footer of dump page) provides enough description for example :

```
The main 'geoname' table has the following fields :
---------------------------------------------------
geonameid         : integer id of record in geonames database
name              : name of geographical point (utf8) varchar(200)
asciiname         : name of geographical point in plain ascii characters, varchar(200)
alternatenames    : alternatenames, comma separated varchar(5000)
latitude          : latitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)
longitude         : longitude in decimal degrees (wgs84)
feature class     : see http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html, char(1)
feature code      : see http://www.geonames.org/export/codes.html, varchar(10)
country code      : ISO-3166 2-letter country code, 2 characters
cc2               : alternate country codes, comma separated, ISO-3166 2-letter country code, 60 characters
admin1 code       : fipscode (subject to change to iso code), see exceptions below, see file admin1Codes.txt for display names of this code; varchar(20)
admin2 code       : code for the second administrative division, a county in the US, see file admin2Codes.txt; varchar(80) 
admin3 code       : code for third level administrative division, varchar(20)
admin4 code       : code for fourth level administrative division, varchar(20)
population        : bigint (8 byte int) 
elevation         : in meters, integer
dem               : digital elevation model, srtm3 or gtopo30, average elevation of 3''x3'' (ca 90mx90m) or 30''x30'' (ca 900mx900m) area in meters, integer. srtm processed by cgiar/ciat.
timezone          : the timezone id (see file timeZone.txt) varchar(40)
modification date : date of last modification in yyyy-MM-dd format
```

Also about the varchar(5000) we should know about the 64kb size of each row in MySQL 5.0 or later:
[Is a VARCHAR(20000) valid in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303476/is-a-varchar20000-valid-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

This is my note after I imported successfully.

As of writing I was testing with MySQL 5.7.16 on Windows 7. Follow these steps to import:

1. Download desired data file from the [official download page](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/). In my case I chose **cities1000.zip** because it's much smaller in size (21MB) than the all-inclusive **allcountries.zip** (1.4GB).
2. Create the following schema and table according to **readme.txt** on the download page, where the fields are specified below the text "the main 'geoname' table has the following fields".

   ```
   CREATE SCHEMA geonames DEFAULT CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

   CREATE TABLE geonames.cities1000 (
    id                INT,
    name              VARCHAR(200),
    ascii_name        VARCHAR(200),
    alternate_names   VARCHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    latitude          DECIMAL(10, 7),
    longitude         DECIMAL(10, 7),
    feature_class     CHAR(1),
    feature_code      VARCHAR(10),
    country_code      CHAR(2),
    cc2               CHAR(60),
    admin1_code       VARCHAR(20),
    admin2_code       VARCHAR(80),
    admin3_code       VARCHAR(20),
    admin4_code       VARCHAR(20),
    population        BIGINT,
    elevation         INT,
    dem               INT,
    timezone          VARCHAR(100),
    modification_date DATE
   )
    CHARACTER SET utf8;
   ```

   Field names are arbitrary as long as the column size and field types are the same as specified. `alternate_names` are specially defined with the character set `utf8mb4` because the values for this column in the file contain 4-byte unicode characters which are not supported by the character set `utf8` of MySQL.
3. Check the values of these parameters: character_set_client, character_set_results, character_set_connection. <sup>[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156926/4357087)</sup>

   ```
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
   ```

   If they are not utf8mb4, then change them:

   ```
   SET character_set_client = utf8mb4;
   SET character_set_results = utf8mb4;
   SET character_set_connection = utf8mb4;
   ```
4. Import data from file using `LOAD DATA INFILE ...`

   ```
   USE geonames;

   LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\cities1000.txt' INTO TABLE cities1000
   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 (id, name, ascii_name, alternate_names, latitude, longitude, feature_class, feature_code,
                          country_code, cc2, admin1_code, admin2_code, admin3_code, admin4_code, population, @val1,
                          @val2, timezone, modification_date)
   SET elevation = if(@val1 = '', NULL, @val1), dem = if(@val2 = '', NULL, @val2);
   ```

   Explanation for the statement:

   - The file should be placed under a designated location by MySQL for importing data from files. You can check the location with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'secure_file_priv';`.  In my case it's `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads`. In Windows you need to use double slashes to represent one slash in the path. This error would be shown when the path is not given correctly: `[HY000][1290] The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`.
   - With `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` you're telling MySQL what encoding to expect from the file. When this is not given explicitly, or the column encoding is not utf8mb4, an error prompt like this will be seen: `[HY000][1300] Invalid utf8 character string: 'Gorad Safija,SOF,Serdica,Sofi,Sofia,Sofiae,Sofie,Sofii,Sofij,Sof'`. <sup>[5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html)</sup> In my case I found it's due to the existence of Gothic letters in the alternate names, such as  (id 727011),  (id 3464975), and  (id 3893894). These letters need to be stored as 4-byte characters (utf8mb4) while my then encoding was utf8 which only supports up to 3-byte characters. <sup>[6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)</sup> You can change column encoding after the table is created:

     ```
     ALTER TABLE cities1000 MODIFY alternate_names VARCHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
     ```

     To check the encoding of a column:

     ```
     SELECT character_set_name, COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_schema = 'geonames' AND table_name = 'cities1000' AND column_name = 'alternate_names';
     ```

     To test if the characters can be stored:

     ```
     UPDATE cities1000 SET alternate_names = '' WHERE id = 1;
     ```
   - Values for some columns need to be "improved" before they are inserted, such as `elevation` and `dem`. They are of type INT and values for them from the file could be empty strings, which can't be stored by an INT type column. So you need to convert those empty strings to null for those columns. The latter part of the statement just serves this purpose. This error would be shown when the values are not property converted first: `[HY000][1366] Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'elevation' at row 1`. <sup>[3](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), [4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111044/94778)</sup>

#### References

1. http://www.geonames.org/
2. http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/
3. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html
4. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/111044/94778
5. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html
6. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html
7. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35156926/4357087
8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Thanks, the utf8mb4 solved some issues I had. I needed places from the entire world for my project. So I made the id the primary key, and made name and ascii-name an index. This speeds up the performance a lot.

Comment: Awesome. In case of "parameter not defined" errors, it appears the use of user-values like val1 and val2 require declaring "Allow User Variables=True" in the connection string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22604492/6079533

Comment: cc2 must be at least 100 characters