# Parameter '@myLeft' must be defined

Tags: mysql

My question is quite similar to already answered ones but yet not. I'd like some help sorting this out.

I'm trying to add data to a database table but I get keeping the titled error. Here's my MySQL-code:

```
Dim objCmdInsert As New MySqlCommand("LOCK TABLE threads WRITE;SET @myLeft := lft;SELECT @myLeft FROM threads WHERE threadid = '" & Request.QueryString("id") & "';UPDATE threads SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;UPDATE threads SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;INSERT INTO threads(threadid, category, userid, ipaddress, section, subject, summary, body, tags, postedat, updatedat, rating, status, lft, rgt) VALUES(?threadid, ?category, ?userid, ?ipaddress, ?section, ?subject, ?summary, ?body, ?tags, ?postedat, ?updatedat, ?rating, ?status, @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);UNLOCK TABLES;", objConn)

objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?threadid", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = Guid.NewGuid.ToString()
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?category", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = "articlecomment"
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?ipaddress", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?section", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = DBNull.Value
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?userid", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36).Value = GetStubs.GetUserGuid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString())
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?subject", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = DBNull.Value
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?summary", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = DBNull.Value
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?body", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = CommentBody.Text
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?tags", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = DBNull.Value
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?postedat", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString()
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?updatedat", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString()
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?rating", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = "0"
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?status", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = "Open"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem by making an extensive Google search for undefined parameters in MySQL. This article ([MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Parameter ‘@id’ must be defined](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2009/05/mysqldatamysqlclientmysqlexception-parameter-id-must-be-defined.html)) covers the basics of the problem. It's as far as I understand related to an upgrade of the connector.

You need to add `Allow User Variables=True` in the connection string in order to use custom variables. Pretty simple solution to an equally tough problem. ;)

Comment: you sir, are a hero.

Comment: Simple solution, Thank you

Comment: Thanks and again Thanks

Comment: Much Appreciate it!, Just save my say! Thanks

Comment: This was so helpful!

Comment: Would it have killed Oracle to make the message say what the real problem was, or at least note that this setting is a possible cause of the problem?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: connStr = "Server=localhost;Database=dbname;Uid=root;Pwd='pswrd';Allow User Variables=True;"

Answer (score 1):

The error is very much informative, you are just using `@myLeft` parameter in your query without defining it. you ned to define that parameter like the others you have done.

```
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("?myLeft",...
```

Comment: I believe the error occurs already before the insert statement while it still updates the lft, rgt values. Therefore defining the parameter as you suggest would still return the same error wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
objCmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@myLeft", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = 1212;
```

You probably have to do it for EACH occurrence of that parameter.

It's not clear to me what's the meaning of `SET @myLeft := lft;` (You are trying to assign column value to parameter)

Answer (score -3):

Before using @myLeft, you need to declare it. For example, assuming @myLeft is an INT:

```
DECLARE @myLeft INT;
```

Comment: I tried declaring the parameter but it still returns the same error.