# How to allow empty string for integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have integer fields in a table. The POSTs are sent by a complicated JavaScript. They send empty strings like "" but as you guessed MySQL doesn't allow empty strings in integer fields. Are there any options to allow empty strings? Like if it takes an empty string it will save it as NULL.

Comment: What language is your backend in? `PHP`? `Python`? etc?

Comment: In most scripting languages, the POSTed data is a string. You must use the language's built-in cast functions to perform the conversion.

Comment: @AndrewDunai, it is PHP and Apache. Latest versions.

Comment: So you want to store an empty STRING in an INTEGER-type field?

Comment: @BenM, no, I want to convert "" to NULL.

Comment: You need to explicitly set `NULL`. Please see my answer.

Comment: This should be done in you code, not database. Please post the code that you use to update/insert data.

Comment: @SalmanA, the code is `$db->insert("USERS",$_POST)`;

Comment: @ilhan you did not mention which db library you are using. Perhaps pre-processing the POST array (e.g. `if($_POST["num"] === "") $_POST["num"] = null;`) might help.

Comment: @SalmanA, yes but there are too much different parameters across the app, I'll need to per-process at least 300 parameters in different locations. In other servers it works without problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Removing `sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` from my.ini has solved the issue.

Edit: Removing the line above works but it is a bad idea. It allows to have things like 0000-00-00  or empty string dates. Better keep the line above and don't insert empty sting into an integer field, instead convert empty string into NULL and then insert that NULL into integer field.

Comment: I had to clear SQL mode explicitly in my.ini on wamp environment to get this working. To clear the SQL mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using sql-mode=""

Comment: @TomCat Thanks, sql-mode="" below [mysqld] in my.cnf (on Linux) solved the error message I had when importing Geonames data.

Answer (score 39):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. **For Current Mysql Session (Temporary Solution)**

First, execute a query to get the current SQL mode of your MySQL server.

```
    mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
    +----------------------------------------------------------------+
    | @@sql_mode                                                     |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------+
    |STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION  |
    +----------------------------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If the result contains `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, you have to remove that value to allow the insert query to pass a NULL value. Make sure your MySQL User has privileges to apply these changes and restart the MySQL Server after applying this.

```
    SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

2. **For Life Time of Mysql (Permanent Solution)**

You have to update my.cnf file. The location of that file is \etc\my.cnf or \etc\mysql\mysql.cnf

There will be some default parameters set under [mysqld] like

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
```

Just add one line under that

```
sql-mode=""
```

Make sure to restart Mysql Server after changing this file. Normally root user will be the owner of the file so you have to log in with the root user on the server.

**For more details understand what this SQL mode does.**

***STRICT_TRANS_TABLES***

Enable strict SQL mode for transactional storage engines, and when possible for non-transactional storage engines. For details, see Strict SQL Mode.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables

***NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER***

Prevent the GRANT statement from automatically creating new user accounts if it would otherwise do so unless authentication information is specified. The statement must specify a nonempty password using IDENTIFIED BY or an authentication plugin using IDENTIFIED WITH.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user

***NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION***

Control automatic substitution of the default storage engine when a statement such as CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE specifies a storage engine that is disabled or not compiled in.

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_engine_substitution

***Edit*:** **Warning:** Setting blank SQL Mode removes the validations. It's better to understand the purpose of each mode and set it accordingly.

Comment: I had to use sql-mode="" like TomCat said in comments, otherwise there was still an error `mysqlimport: Error: 1366, Incorrect integer value: '' for column` (and the documentation says TRADITIONAL is equivalent to STRICT_TRANS_TABLES). By the way, the path was /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Thanks for saying that the line should go below [mysqld], we can easily forget.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the column allows for `NULL` values, you must explicitly tell MySQL to use a value of `NULL`, rather than passing an empty string (which is cast to `0`):

```
INSERT INTO table (column_name) VALUES (NULL);
```

Comment: (not related to the downvote) . . . I'm guessing the OP is using `insert` rather than `update`, but the similar logic applies.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff You may be right. I've amended the answer to better suit the OP's specific situation (with `INSERT`).

Comment: @BenM, The JavaScript posts ""  (or PHP gets "") so the Zend DB tries to `INSERT INTO table (column_name) VALUES ("")`;

Comment: I would say that you don't always have control at the query level. I am using a library that is currently doing this error.