# Data not Insert not Insert with Blank textbox Using PHP Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to ask if anyone know how to solved my issue.
I have Form with 4  and I want save the data into the database.

the problem is I want add data with blank input.
Example 1 :

Consumer Request : data = test and submit the form. the others text box I want it blank and mydatabase only Consumer Request data insert into database.

Example 1 :
Check & Verification : data = 'test', and submit the form. the others text box I want it blank and mydatabase only Check & Verification data insert into database.

The real issue is If I only insert 1 text box the system cannot work. but if I insert all 4 texbox the data will insert into database without no issue.

Sorry if my explaination a bit confius and my bad English.

```html
<div align="center">
 <h2>Add Product</h2>
 <form onSubmit="return saveData();" action="user.php" method="post">
 <ul style="text-decoration: none; list-style: none">
 <li>Consumer Request :</li>
 <li><input type="text" name="cons_req"></li>
 <li>Check & Verification</li>
 <li><input type="text" name="chk_ver"></li>
 <li>MNP Transaction</li>
 <li><input type="text" name="mnp_trns"></li>
 <li>Point</li>
 <li><input type="text" name="point"></li><br>
 <li><input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="save" class="btn-danger"><br><br><br><br>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </form>
</div>
<div align="center">
 <table style="color: #fff; background: #333; border: 2px solid #fff">
  <tr style="color: #fff; background:rgba(201,5,8,1.00); border: 2px solid #fff">
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">Consumer Request</th>
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">Check & Verification</th>
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">MNP Transaction</th>
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">Point</th>
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">Update</th>
   <th style="border: 2px solid #fff; padding: 5px">Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="data" style="color: #333; background: #fff; border: 2px solid #fff" align="center"></tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

and below is my process code.

```html
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mifaresystem"); // Create database connection

  
  $msg = ""; // Initialize message variable

  
  if(isset($_POST['save'])) // If upload button is clicked ...
  {
   $cons_req = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cons_req']);
   $chk_ver = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['chk_ver']);
   $mnp_trns = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mnp_trns']);
   $point = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['point']);
   
   $sql = "INSERT INTO productivity_request (`consumer_request`, `check_ver`, `mnp_transaction`, `point`) VALUES ('$cons_req', '$chk_ver', '$mnp_trns', '$point')";
   // execute query
   if(mysqli_query($db, $sql))
 {
   header("Location: javainsert.php");
exit;
 }else{
   echo json_encode('problem');
 }
  }
?>
```

Comment: I already know the issue. It because mydatabase for 1 of the data type is INT. Anyone how to insert empty string to INT?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606483/how-to-allow-empty-string-for-integer-in-mysql   but it is definitely a bad idea! Rather change the data type of your field!

Comment: Thanks. I already change my data type. and it work. :)