# VTiger Installation Error MySQL Server should be configured with: sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, vtiger

I have read a few threads on this but have yet to find a solution.
I am installing vtiger on Ubuntu 18.04 – Apache 4.29

I got the same error when using PHP 7.2 so have downgraded to PHP 5.6
I have done the following:
1)

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

#Added the following part to the bottom:

`sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

2. `sudo nano /etc/php.ini`
   #replaced
   `error_reporting = E_ALL`
   #with
   `error_reporting = E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE`

However I still get the below at the Install prerequisites screen

Recommended PHP Settings
error_reporting E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT NOT RECOMMENDED
log_errors Off On

And
MySQL Server should be configured with:
sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
At the Confirm Configuration Settings Screen

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying different things for 2 days now.
Thank you

Comment: Have you manually changed the location for your `php.ini` file to `/etc/php.ini`? Normally, there are two different `php.ini` on Ubuntu. One for CLI that usually are located something like: `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` for the CLI and `/etc/php/8.1/apache/php.ini` for apache (or /fpm/ for php-fpm). And 8.1 is just an example. It should be your current PHP version.

Comment: Apologies, my path for the php.ini file is 
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini

Comment: did you restart mysql after editing my.cnf and php.ini? If you don't  your changes wont take effect.

Comment: Changes to `/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini` will only affect PHP through the command line, not through the web server. Check if you have `/etc/php/5.6/apache/php.ini` or `/etc/php/5.6/fpm/php.ini` as well. If you do, add the same changes there. If it's apache, restart apache after updating the ini-file. If it's fpm, then restart php-fpm after the changes.

Comment: You should really upgrade your PHP version. PHP 5.6 hasn't been supported (incl. not getting any security updates) for several years now.

Comment: You can read here for solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606483/how-to-allow-empty-string-for-integer-in-mysql/39409037#39409037